# Threading with iOS and waiting for function completion

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I'm calling a function on a thread in my project.

```
 [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(shortVibration) withObject: nil];
```

It's called in a loop.

I would like for the function to be called on its own thread.

I don't want it to be called at the same time (if this thread Call is in a loop... and it is)

So, I don't want to call my thread function again until the last one is done executing.

How can I do this?

Comment: Step one: Don't call `performSelectorInBackground`. Just don't. NSOperation and Grand Central Dispatch are at your service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> don't want it to be called at the same time

That suggests a "serial queue". That could be a dispatch queue or an operation queue. But a serial queue is one that can run only one task at a time.

Or, you can decouple the loop from the repeating vibration and set up a timer to run while your loop progresses which will repeatedly call your vibration routine and then cancel the timer at the end of the loop. You can either use a standard `NSTimer` and have it dispatch the calls to whatever queue you want, or you can use a GCD timer, which you can schedule on a background queue.

It depends upon the details of how this vibration routine works and the nature of your loop. We'd need more detail (e.g. describe the broader problem and the nature of this "vibrate" routine) to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should take a look at NSOperationQueue which allows you to call functions in own created Queues. The Queues are executed on an own Thread.

For example:

```
NSOperationQueue *backgroundQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
backgroundQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
backgroundQueue.name = @"com.foo.bar";

[_backgroundQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
       do what you want.... here you also have access to properties in your class.
}];
```

With the operationCount you can handle the count of parallel executed operations. You can also create an own Subclass of NSOperation and execute your code there. Then you have to add the Operation like this [_backgroundQueue addOperation:SubclassOfNSOperation].

I hope this helps you a little. Out of your Question I can't get more information to help you more in detail. Post some code perhaps.